# Python ctypes access violation reading

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm trying to communicate with a device through a DLL with python, but I'm getting "OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000". I've read other topics, tried the solutions there, but nothing worked.

Here is the code:

```
from ctypes import *

Papo32 = WinDLL("lib\\Papo32.dll")
Interlnk = WinDLL("lib\\Interlnk.dll")
Intfac32 = WinDLL("lib\\Intfac32.dll")
Spider32 = WinDLL("lib\\Spider32.dll")

ACQ_setup = Spider32.S8_ACQSetup
ACQ_setup.argtypes = [c_long, POINTER(c_long)]
ACQ_setup.restype = c_long

chans = [1]
n_chans = len(chans)
chans = (c_long * 8)(*chans)

error = ACQ_setup(n_chans, chans)
print(error)
```

This is the error:

**error = ACQ_setup(c_long(n_chans), chans_array(*chans))

OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000**

The error doesn't occur when the array is empty.

I have this from the documentation:

```
S8_ACQSetup

Syntax:
    result = S8_ACQSetup(Num, *Chans);

Parameters:
    Input:
        • Num - long
          Number of measured values per channels
        • Chans - long
          List of measured channels

    Output:
        Result of the function (long):
        If the result of the function is non-zero, an error has occurred.

Description:
    The desired channels will be activated for measuring.
```

And I'm following this example in VB5, provided by the manufacturer:

```
Declare Function S8_ACQSetup& Lib "SPIDER32.DLL" (ByVal num As Long, Chans As Long)

Dim ChanArray(10) As Long

ChanArray(1) = 0
S8_Error = S8_ACQSetup(1, ChanArray(1))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not `chans = (c_long * n_chans)(*chans)`? And the error doesn;t occur when the array is empty or when you pass 0 as the 1st argument?

Comment: I could write this way, but I don't think that makes any difference, the error persists. When the array is empty (`chans = []`).

Comment: Actually, I just tried to pass a non-empty array with 0 as the first argument, and the error doesn't occured.

Comment: I thought so.... Did you try setting the vector to be of size 10 (like in the *VB* example)?

Comment: Yes, and I tried to pass an array with 10 elements too (`chans = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`),  I get the same error.

Comment: Hmmm, try replacing *c\_long* by *c\_longlong* everywhere in this piece of code, and let me know if you notice any difference.

Comment: The error persists, no difference.